# Phantomjs connection to Facebook fails SSL handshake

Tags: javascript, facebook, ssl, phantomjs

I am trying to build a web scraper for Facebook using phantomjs. The connection fails due to SSL handshake failure. I get the same result for twitter, but google works fine. Does anyone know a solution for this? I am running phantomjs version 1.9.7. I have posted my code and my error output below.

```js
var system = require('system');
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('https://www.facebook.com', function(status){
    console.log("status: " + status);
    if(status === "success"){
        console.log("no error");
    } else {
        console.log("Error opening url \"" + page.reason_url + "\": " + page.reason);
    }
    phantom.exit();

});
```

output:

```
unable to load url: "https://www.facebook.com/"
error code: 6, description: SSL handshake failed
status: fail
Error opening url "undefined": undefined
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

phantomjs defaults to SSL 3.0 when using https. Since SSL 3.0 is disabled on lots of hosts because it is insecure, the SSL handshake will fail. Use `phantomjs --ssl-protocol=any` to make phantomjs use a more modern version (TLS1.0 or higher).

Comment: This help me to loggin in facebook... `https://www.facebook.com/login.php`