# Phantomjs fail to load the address

Tags: javascript, ssl, web-scraping, phantomjs

I'm trying, thanks to PhantomJS, to scrape this webpage : https://www.koshkamashkaeshop.com/fr/28-robes-Koshka-Mashka
but it failed to load every time. I thought that it was because of the https.
Here is  my .sh code :

```
phantomjs  --ignore-ssl-errors=yes test.js
```

Here is my test.js code :

```
page.open(url, function (status) {

var content = page.evaluate(function()
 {
  if (status !== 'success') {
     console.log('FAIL to load the address');
  }else{

  }
 }
)})
```

Comment: What PhantomJS version do you have and does the page load when you call PhantomJS with the `--ssl-protocol=any` option?

Comment: I have the 1.9 version. I tried --ssl-protocol=any but not working

Answer (score 6):

I know this is old but i got the same error

```
phantomjs --debug=yes --ignore-ssl-errors=true --ssl-protocol=any --web-security=true rasterize.js url output.pdf
```

credit: https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10178

Answer (score 1):

It is the same problem as described at [Phantomjs connection to Facebook fails SSL handshake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29058557/phantomjs-connection-to-facebook-fails-ssl-handshake/29058889#29058889): Phantomjs defaults to SSL 3.0 and lots of sites have SSL 3.0 disabled. You need to use

```
 phantomjs  --ssl-protocol=any test.js
```

Comment: The SSL part works for me with 1.9.0. But there seem to be further problems after the SSL connection.

Answer (score 1):

`page.evaluate()` is the sandboxed page context in PhantomJS. It has no access to variables defined outside. Also, if you want to see console messages from the page context, you need to register to the [`page.onConsoleMessage`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-console-message.html) event. You don't need the page context in this case.

The other problem is that PhantomJS version < 1.9.8 uses SSLv3 by default, but because of the POODLE vulnerability most webservers have disabled SSLv3 support, so you need to explicitly add the `--ssl-protocol=tlsv1` commandline option.

Working code with PhantomJS 1.9.0:

```
page.open(url, function (status) {
  console.log("status: " + status);
  phantom.exit();
});
```

Of course, if you really want to pass the status into the page context for whatever reason, you need to pass it explicitly:

```
page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg){
    console.log("page: " + msg);
};
page.open(url, function (status) {
    page.evaluate(function(status){
        console.log("status: " + status);
    }, status);
    phantom.exit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if its https, try running

```
phantomjs --ssl-protocol=TLSv1.1 <filename.js>
```

and in addition, add user agent to the code.

e.g.

```
 var page = require('webpage').create();
 page.settings.userAgent = 'SpecialAgent';

 page.open(url,function(status){}
```

This worked for me. :)